# "Intercepting" executable with FTK Imager

Tags: forensics, memory

I want to analyze the traces of a program in my VM by executing it and then capturing the memory and disk using FTK Imager.

However, it looks like --given the environment I have-- the program only runs for a couple seconds, and --since the target program is done before FTK ends-- the memory snapshot doesn't show the executable at all.

What would you do given this situation?

Comment: FTK Imager only captures non-running disk content, not memory.

Comment: There is a button to capture memory

Comment: Funny! I never used FTK Imager for memory capture, didn't even realize the capability was there. So *Volatility* doesn't show any memory remnants in the dump?  Since this is a VM, have you tried simply suspending the VM in lieu of a dump? If this is a Windows system, try using **sysinternals** to watch the processes.

Comment: You understood correctly. Volatility doesn't have anything about the program. I'll try what you say, though.